# Match condition to key on an object and return its value

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, switch-statement

I came across a code in GitHub like this :

```js
function typeToIcon(type) {
  return {
    success: 'check',
    info: 'info-circle',
    warning: 'exclamation-circle',
    error: 'exclamation-triangle',
  }[type];
}

// Log to console
console.log(typeToIcon('info'));
```

Can someone explain how this logic works? What is this called in JS? I have never seen a conditional statement like this before.

Comment: Did you post the wrong code? there is no `conditional statement` in the code you posted.

Comment: It's creating an object (using object literal syntax), then immediately accesses a property on it and returns its value

Comment: So this a worse form of a switch statement, because its creating object everytime the function runs. Its better to use Switch statement here?

Comment: @San Creating objects is cheap, so it's not necessarily that bad. You could optimise it by defining the object outside of the function though. A `switch` statement would work as well, it's just more verbose - too much for some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps if you think of the code as

```js
const lookup = {
  success: 'check',
  info: 'info-circle',
  warning: 'exclamation-circle',
  error: 'exclamation-triangle',
};

function typeToIcon(type) {
  return lookup[type];
}

console.log(typeToIcon('info'));
```

it'll make sense to you

The code in your question just uses the object inline in the return statement

Answer (score 1):

It's not a condition.
This function creates an object with the keys 'success', 'info', 'warning', and 'error', and by calling it with the type parameter it is responding with the value hard-coded into that object.
For better understandability, here is the code in a more readable version.

```
function typeToIcon(type) {
  const dict =  {
    success: 'check',
    info: 'info-circle',
    warning: 'exclamation-circle',
    error: 'exclamation-triangle',
  };
  const value = dict[type];
  return value;
}

// Log to console
console.log(typeToIcon('info'));
```

Answer (score -1):

it return an object which have some keys like: success, info, warning, error.
To access to object by key (in this case is parameter `type`), you need to use square bracket like: objectTypeIcon[type]
typeToIcon('info') -> info-circle

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation

Answer (score -1):

it's one of the three ways to access object properties:

1. Dot property accessor

```js
const hero = {
  name: 'Batman'
};

// Dot property accessor
console.log(hero.name); // => 'Batman'
```

2. Square brackets property accessor

```
const property = 'name';
const hero = {
  name: 'Batman'
};

// Square brackets property accessor:
console.log(hero['name']);   // => 'Batman'
console.log(hero[property]); // => 'Batman'
```

3. Object destructuring

```
const hero = {
  name: 'Batman'
};

// Object destructuring:
const { name } = hero;
console.log(name); // => 'Batman'
```